# C# : Asynchronous routine execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, asynchronous

```
class Program {

    static void Main() {

        int a = sync_routine_1();
        int b = sync_routine_2();

        async_routine_3(a, b);
        sync_routine_4();

    }
}
```

The above is a simple azure webjob. `sync_routine1` & `sync_routine2` will be executed on the database and returns two integers `a` & `b`. These are computed on a sequence of actions on the same database. These two int variables are used as input parameters of an `async_routine_3`. In this routine the data is inserted into another database hosted on a completely different server.

I want to end the execution of instance of `Program` after the completion of `sync_routine4()` irrespective of the execution status of the `async_routine3()`.

> this is not happening and the execution of async_routine3() is stopped half way.

*How do i have to write the async method so as to just execute itself on separate thread when called from main thread and kill itself after completion. I don't want the main thread to wait till the completion of `async_routine3()`.*

What i am asking maynot be a good coding practice but, for the amount of work that needs to be done is too huge. In case of any failures we have a different logging for that method. So i can repeat the process and get the job done of the routine even at a later stage.

Comment: You say *the execution of async_routine3() is stopped half way*, but then go on to say that's exactly what you want. This is quite unclear.

Comment: @CharlesMager I think he wants async_routine3() to finish completely, independently of the main thread exiting.

Comment: @Christoph possibly, though I can't see how you can expect code to carry on executing once the app (job) has exited.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wait for the async routine and you want the thread that is running to exit prior to it completing, you would need to package that async method in another executable and then start that process from within the existing code.